# WiFi connects to network, but cannot connect to internet

Tags: networking, intel-wireless

I am unable to connect to the internet with Ubuntu 12.04.3. The Windows 8.1 partition however can access my WiFi perfectly. From what I've managed to gather my adapter is not being assigned an IPv4 address and cannot ping the router. Running dhclient did not work. Curiously I am able to connect and search with google through the WiFi however no other websites work. A wired connection seems to work the majority if the time.

Details:
Adapter: Intel Wireless-N 7260

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.3 w/ kernel 3.12.2

nm-tool output: https://gist.github.com/bloxgate/7715106

dmesg output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6502541/

If you need more info please ask.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: nm-tool

Comment: Done, sorry it took a while, had to transfer over files to my Windows partition to get them on the internet (can't get to a wired connection at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

It appears, as you've surmised, that the router is giving an IPv6 address, but not IPv4. You also lack a DNS nameserver which is crucial to resolve names like askubuntu.com to numbers like 198.252.206.24. I suggest you right-click the Network Manager icon and Edit Connections. Select the Wireless tab and IPv4 and be certain that the method is set to Automatic (DHCP). As a temporary experiment, you might also try selecting the IPv6 tab and set IPv6 to Ignore. Then close the edit and click the Network Manager icon and disconnect. Wait a few moments for NM to see a change in state and try to connect again. Can you? Can you browse? Does *nm-tool* show an IPv4 address and the all-important DNS nameservers?

You might also look in the administration pages of the router to see if there is any preference for IPv6 to the exclusion of IPv4 and deselect it. I am unaware of such a setting, but new things are introduced every day!

You might also look at other connected devices on the network and compare their addresses. Also, please paste: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

```
dmesg | grep -e wlan -e iwl
```

Comment: Nope can't even connect to my WiFi if IPv6 is set to ignore. IPv4 is set to automatic (DHCP) but still does not work. I can't even ping my router from the affected computer using IPv4 or IPv6.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I've added the output of dmesg | grep -e wlan -e iwl to my post. No other devices connected at the same time should have the same IP. I've setup DHCP reservation to assign the IP address 192.168.1.50 only to my MAC address.

Comment: Is the behavior improved without the DHCP reservation in the router and after rebooting the router?

Comment: Unfortunately I require the DHCP reservation for software on the windows partition to work without requiring constant network reconfiguration when switching between different WiFi networks.